# Concatenate two or more element of the same node of a XML by XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

XML to XML by XSL Transformation where I want to concatenate multiple element like this:

XML code (input):

```xml
<bgo:Sample>
    <bgo:Date>23</bgo:Date>
    <bgo:Month>4</bgo:Month>
    <bgo:Year>2016</bgo:Year>
<bgo:Sample>
```

Required XML code (output):

```xml
<Sample>
  <Start_Date>23/04/2016</Start_Date>
</Sample>
```

Anyone Please suggest me how can concatenate these element through XSLT.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: I can't understand, how can create xslt for these xml

Comment: By spending half an hour with an XSLT tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to concatenate the values to get the desired output. As suggested by @michael.hor257k, please go through XSLT basics by reading through online tutorials.

Here is one way that can be used to concatenate the individual date values into a formatted date. Please ensure that the namespace for `bgo:` has been correctly mapped. I have not considered it in the sample XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Sample">
        <xsl:variable name="separator" select="'/'" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <Start_Date>
                <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
                <xsl:value-of select="Month" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
                <xsl:value-of select="Year" />
            </Start_Date>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give you the required output.

```
<Sample>
    <Start_Date>23/4/2016</Start_Date>
</Sample>
```